Dropboxsign embedded into lwc iframe
I have two questions, first is this error: Missing parameter: client_id that I face when I try to use sign_url that I get from https://api.hellosign.com/v3/embedded/sign_url/' + signatureId, in the documentation I don't see client_id being used, in this forum post their developer mentioned using library solution and second response that mentions using clientid in the header didn't help too. For all callouts I'm using API key as auth method and they are all made via apex and sign URL is passed to lwc. So the first question would be how to properly generate sign URL that it can be displayed in iframe. And second question is, how to properly use the library that dropbox developer mentions in the response? I downloaded it and make a static resource with the zip in it, but when I try to
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import HELLOSIGNJS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/hellosignJs';
    connectedCallback(){
    getLeadData({recordId: this.recordId})
    .then(result => {
        console.log('result: ' + JSON.stringify(result))
    })
    console.log('after');

    loadScript(this, HELLOSIGNJS + "/src/embedded.js")
    .then(() => {
        console.log('loaded successfully');
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error loading HelloSign SDK', error);
    });
    console.log('after' + 2);
}

I received GET https://mySalesforce.sandbox.my.site.com/website/resource/1731541833000/hellosignJs/src/embedded.js 404 (Not Found)

The linked documentation page states an API key or OAuth 2.0 can be used. What of the two do you want to use? If you go for the latter, you can read about its client_id here, for example. But are you sure you want this approach? Regarding your other question - have you considered to make use of OpenAPI and Apex? Maybe you should add some information on your use case.

Hi @FelixvanHove, i updated the question a bit, ive been using api key for auth and apex to do all the callouts(two of them), as for the second part, I'm not sure how to use stuff that you linked here, can you elaborate please?

Importing the OpenAPI definition makes Salesforce generate Apex classes for you to call. You can then use them to access HelloSign's API from your own Apex, as if the API was part of Salesforce. There is a helpful Trailhead for this. But from what I can read now in your question, Apex access to HelloSign is indeed not what you need.

were you able to find some solution to this?
